# How to create get direction button in mapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am working on my app, it has the mapView inside and the user location. Then, I need to get direction from user location to particular place on the map, how do I do that. I'am searching around and it seem to be like that Apple does not allow to do it on Apple map. 
Please give me some advices and thanks so much.

Comment: using the MapView you can not get directions.  You create a URL to open the Maps.app and route directions there. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: Here my situation, I built a taxi application, so I need to estimate the price for customer before they start to using that service, I can use MKMapItem to switch to map application but now I can't use it to estimate the price.

Comment: You can't use Apple Maps then.  You will have to use the Google's Routing api to get all the legs of a route.  From there you can get distance and estimate time of route.

Comment: @KucKu, see my answer below. Either the MapQuest or Google Directions Web API can directly access the distance a route will take.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW5

Answer (score 0):

As John commented, you can't get directions via a `UIMapView`, as Apple doesn't provide an API you can use to do so. If you really need an API for directions and don't want to write it yourself, check out the following APIs:

- [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/apple-ios-maps-api)
- [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/)
- [Google Directions Web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Using one of the listed sources, you can make an `HTTP` request to a server that will return a result (likely in `JSON`) that includes both directions and an ETA.

For example, the following MapQuest API call will return a `JSON` item called `distance`, which contains the formatted distance (in miles) that the recommended route between Lancaster and York will take. Just remember to pass in your API key.

`http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&from=Lancaster,PA&to=York,PA&callback=renderNarrative`

For further explanation, have a look at the [MapQuest documentation](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#response).

Comment: Not a problem, and welcome to StackOverflow. If this answer accurately answered your question, please press the checkmark next to it